# Get correct value in nav - based on url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my models are:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
    has_many :regions

end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :country
end
```

part of routes

```
resources :countries, :path => ''
 resources :countries, :path => '', :only => [] do
  resources :regions, :path => ''
    resources :regions, :path => '', :only => [] do
     resources :houses do
  collection do
    get 'tags/:tag', to: 'houses#index', as: :tag
    end
  end
```

Region_controller:

```
def show
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @region = Region.find(params[:id])
end
```

Main-nav:

```
 %ul.nav
        %li
          = link_to "home", root_path
        %li.dropdown
          %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "/nl"}
            = t('navigation.nav.houses')
            = @region.name
```

The region name (@region.name) of the main navigation is filled in by the controller variable. This works fine..so i get nice 'custom' main navigation per region. But now i want also do does by country path ...so when a visitor is on /locale/italy in the name "italy' is showed in the main navigation. How can i do this? Conditions in the view layer?

In the main nav the variable @region.name shows the correct region name based on controller logic. But how deal i when a visitor is on the country page? The main nav code is @region.name.

Thanks..remco

Comment: Please rephrase this: "But now i want also do does by country path ...so when a visitor is on /locale/italy in the name "italy' is showed in the main navigation". I don't get what you actually want.

Comment: mathieugagne - updated question

Comment: Alright, I get it now. So what have you tried? Seems you have limited knowledge of Rails. Are you familiar with `helpers`?

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/helpers/region_helper.rb
module RegionHelper

  def region_name
    return session[:region] if session[:region].present?
    @region ||= Region.find('however you find')
    @region.name
  end

end
```

OR

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :prepare_region

  protected

  def prepare_region
    @region_name = session[:region] || Region.find('however you find')
    session[:region] = @region_name
  end

end
```

Then in your view, use either `region_name` or `@region_name` or `@region.name` if you modify the second example. Use a combination of whatever code you feel works for you.

Comment: mathieu.thanks..i don't think this is what i am looking for. If i had only 1 country record...this would work in my country_controller
@region = Country.find(1) and show 'region' in the view. But there are 10 in my DB...

Comment: So what do you need to show? You need all of them? `Country.all`